# View parameterized queries ran on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, oracle11g

I would like to view parameterized update, select, and delete statements executed on an oracle database.

I can see the query by running the following:

```
select * from v$sqlarea where parsing_schema_name = 'SCHEMA_NAME' order by last_active_time desc
```

But I want to also view the parameters that go with the SQL in the SQL_TEXT column. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by parameterized you mean bind variables, you need `V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE`. Search it by the `SQL_ID` you found in `V$SQLAREA`.

Each row represents a variable captured by position, so you'll have to match it up with your names from your query.